# java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object java.util.Optional.value accessible:

Tags: java, logging, junit, error-handling

```
java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make field private final java.lang.Object java.util.Optional.value accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.util" to unnamed module @6b26e945
```

I am getting this error when I run my JUnit code.
Error arises around the following code block.

```
Optional<RolesDTO> roleDTOEmployee = roles.stream()
        .filter(r -> r.getName().equals(RolesEnum.valueOf(roleName).getRoleName())).findFirst();

if (logger.isInfoEnabled()) {
    logger.info("roleDTOEmployee {}", gson.toJson(roleDTOEmployee));
}
```

stacktrace:

```
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.checkCanSetAccessible(Field.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Field.setAccessible(Field.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:157)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:423)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:661)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:648)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:603)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:583)
```

on removing logger.info(), code JUnit runs perfectly. I would like to understand this behaviour. And is there a workaround it, so I don't have to remove logger.

Comment: Does `gson.toJson(roleDTOEmployee.orElse(null))` work? It seems like [gson doesn't support `Optional`](https://github.com/google/gson/issues/1102).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error typically thrown if you are using higher JDK version (8+) & one of modules (in this case `com.google.gson.Gson` is compatible with lower JDK version).

Can you please check both  JDK version Gson version downgrade your JDK if possible & required. That way your error might be gone. Other possibility is to upgrade `com.google.gson.Gson` version so that it is compatible with your JDK.

Another workaround (which is typically not recommended) is pass VM args to avoid above error:

```
-Xmx1536M --add-exports=java.base/sun.nio.ch=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.lang.reflect=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports=jdk.unsupported/sun.misc=ALL-UNNAMED
```

Comment: yes. version was not compatible. on upgrading it works too. thanks.